# Limit selection to visible not working in orthographic perspective

Tags: selection-tools

I am using blender 2.73 and I want the model to be opaque/solid in the viewport instead of this.

[image]

I know I can do this by using limit selection to visible but it doesn't work in orthographic perspective. It works in user perspective however. Is there something I can do?

I also tried moving the object into a new blend file but the problem persisted.

Comment: Limit selection to visible works for me in both modes.

Answer (score 4):

I reduced the clipping distance down from 1000000 to the default 1000 and scaled down the model and it solved the problem.

Comment: Had the same problem. Spent some time trying to find a solution, but with no result. Thanks for help man!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Blender Bug to me that Clip: End affects the visibility of mesh data.
(Blender 2.78c)

[image: Clip 2000]

[image: Clip 20000000]